# How does the SQL Server that comes with Visual Studio differ from the full one?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

How does the SQL Server that comes with Visual Studio differ from the full one?

And will I be able to use it to create a simple database for collecting metrics from a tool that I'm writing?

What's the easiest way of getting a console up where I can type insert/select/create etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Express, which comes with Visual Studio, only supports up to 4GB of data, 1GB of RAM, and 1 CPU.  It also doesn't include Analysis Services or Integration Services.

However, you can download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which is the "console" you asked for, as a free add-on for SQL Express.  You can also download Reporting Services, if you need it.

See:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7522A683-4CB2-454E-B908-E805E9BD4E28&displaylang=en

Otherwise, the relational engine itself is basically identical to the one used in SQL Standard (there are a few additional minor differences).  SQL Express is not throttled from a performance perspective.

Comment: Cheers for this, very helpful.

Comment: and of course, you can easily detach a database from SQL Server Express, and re-attach it on a "full" SQL Server - no conversion, no messing around needed - the database file formats are IDENTICAL.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the details here at [Microsoft SQL Server Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx).  The version shipped with Visual Studio is Express under the Free Editions.